# Date converstion using strptime skips UTC part

Tags: python, utc, python-datetime, string-to-datetime

I am trying to convert string variable to date object the output doesnt have the UTC component.

Here is the sample code .. Appreciate your help!

```py
import datetime
data="2016-01-19T00:00:00.000-0800"
result2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(data[0:23],"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
print(result2)
```

Comment: The code that you have provided works. What is the thing that doesn't work? You're mentioning a "UTC component". Do you mean that you want the timezone indicated as "-0800" in the string to be included in the datetime object returned?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are slicing out the `utc` part of the string in `data[0:23]`, if you want to get a `datetime` object with `timezone` information you can do this instead:

```py
import datetime

data = "2016-01-19T00:00:00.000-0800"
result2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(data,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
print(result2)

>>> 2016-01-19 00:00:00-08:00
```